# Java Properties object to String

Tags: java, string, properties

I have a Java `Properties` object that I load from an in-memory `String`, that was previously loaded into memory from the actual `.properties` file like this:

```
this.propertyFilesCache.put(file, FileUtils.fileToString(propFile));
```

The util `fileToString` actually reads in the text from the file and the rest of the code stores it in a `HashMap` called `propertyFilesCache`.  Later, I read the file text from the `HashMap` as a `String` and reload it into a Java `Properties` object like so:

```
String propFileStr = this.propertyFilesCache.get(fileName);
Properties tempProps = new Properties();
try {
    tempProps.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(propFileStr.getBytes()));
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.debug(e.getMessage());
}
tempProps.setProperty(prop, propVal);
```

At this point, I've replaced my property in my in-memory property file and I want to get the text from the `Properties` object as if I was reading a `File` object like I did up above.  Is there a simple way to do this or am I going to have to iterate over the properties and create the `String` manually?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
public static String getPropertyAsString(Properties prop) {    
  StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
  prop.list(new PrintWriter(writer));
  return writer.getBuffer().toString();
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this will _not_ give you a straight rendering of the properties back, i.e. you can't just pop out that string into a file and load it back as a properties file. This is because that **Properties.list()** method prepends a header onto the list:

`-- listing properties --`

More likely you'd want to use the **Properties.store()** method described in the comment from @joev comment below.

Comment: bad and ugly recomendation because this have unexcepted beahviour: (var5.length() > 40) and

Answer (score 18):

There seems to be a problem with @Isiu answer. After that code Properties are truncated, like there is some limit to string length. Proper way is to use code like this:

```
public static String getPropertyAsString(Properties prop) { 
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    try {
        prop.store(writer, "");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ...
    }
    return writer.getBuffer().toString();
}
```

Comment: You get a header with a time stamp with that method.

Answer (score 9):

It's not directly related to your question but if you just want to print out properties for debugging you can do something like this

```
properties.list(System.out);
```

Comment: Or even just call `.toString()` if you're using a logging solution.  It uses `ConcurrentHashMap`s implementation.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Java 8 or above, here is a single statement solution with the possibility to control the format by yourself:

```
String properties = System.getProperties().entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(e -> e.getKey() + ":" + e.getValue())
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't completely understand what you're trying to do, but you can use the Properties class' store(OutputStream out, String comments) method.  From the [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store(java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String)):

> public void store(OutputStream out,
>                    String comments)
>             throws IOException
>
> Writes this property list (key and element pairs) in this Properties table to the output stream in a format suitable for loading into a Properties table using the load(InputStream) method.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as below also:

```
Properties p = System.getProperties();
Enumeration keys = p.keys();
while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
    String key = (String)keys.nextElement();
    String value = (String)p.get(key);
    System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another function to print all the values of a field is :

```
public static <T>void   printFieldValue(T obj)
{
    System.out.printf("###" + obj.getClass().getName() + "###");
    for (java.lang.reflect.Field field : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        String name = field.getName();
        Object value = null;
        try{
            value = field.get(obj);
        }catch(Throwable e){}
        System.out.printf("#Field name: %s\t=> %s%n", name, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `list` method is incorrect because it should be used only for debugging purposes

> Prints this property list out to the specified output stream.
> This method is useful for debugging.

It doesn't escape keys which contains special characters, like `=` or `:`.

The `store` method should be used, but it inserts a comment and timestamp. The following code removes these additional lines and returns a text with normalized new lines.

#### Java

```java
public static String propertiesToString(Properties properties) throws IOException {
    if (properties == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (properties.isEmpty()) {
        return "";
    }
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    properties.store(writer, null);
    String text = normalizeNewLines(writer.toString());
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(text.split("\n")));
    lines.remove(0);
    return lines.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
}

private static String normalizeNewLines(String text) {
    return text.replace("\r\n", "\n").replace("\r", "\n");
}
```

#### Groovy

```
static String propertiesToString(Properties properties) {
    if (properties.is(null)) {
        return null
    }
    if (properties.isEmpty()) {
        return ''
    }
    def writer = new StringWriter()
    properties.store(writer, null)
    def lines = normalizeNewLines(writer).split('\n') as List
    lines.remove(0)
    return lines.join('\n')
}

private static String normalizeNewLines(String text) {
    return text.replace('\r\n', '\n').replace('\r', '\n')
}
```