# How to fix truststore type from jks to pkcs12

Tags: ssl, keystore, jks, pkcs#12, truststore

How to fix truststore type from jks to pkcs12.
I found a link https://www.baeldung.com/java-keystore to change the type but -Dkeystore.type=pkcs12 I couldn't this parameter where I can put? Could you clarify how to change and see that it is changed ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose type of your keystore is pkcs12.

You should use `-Dkeystore.type=pkcs12` property in VM Options on IDE.

Here is solution how you can print your System properties:
[Java Properties object to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579113/java-properties-object-to-string)

or implement it in your code:

```
char[] pwdArray = "password".toCharArray();
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
ks.load(new FileInputStream("newKeyStoreFileName.p12"), pwdArray);
```